# How do I replace a string in JADE markup?

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the following code:

```
ul.events
            each event, i in data
                li 
                    strong #{event.name} - 
                    | Posted By #{event.username}
                    p #{event.description}
                    a(href= '/events/show/#{event.name.replace(' ','-')}', class='btn btn-default') Read More
```

I receive an error because I don't think the way that I've done the .replace is valid.

If anybody has any suggestions or has experienced this before then I would appreciate it if you could offer some advice.

Thanks

Comment: Show the code of that `replace` operation.

Comment: The replace method is part of JADE it is not something I have custom made.

Comment: But you have js within Jade. You should rather do that `replace` operation outside Jade code.

Comment: and then provide the plain string variable to your Jade template.

Comment: Yes correct I could do that and it would be much better but I'm still currently trying to learn Jade and the methods that it boasts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not escaping literal quotes. Simply replace `'` single quotes with double `"`

Like so:

```
event.name.replace(" ", "-")
```

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't notice that. It seems to work fine now. Thank you :)